Fit two dimentional gaussian in dataset
I have a dataset which is a moderately large (1200x1200) array of values. A part of that array has the data that is gaussian along the 2 diagonals. Find the general area of the peak is trivial with a binarize. But then I'm trying to find the actual peak center that obeys a normal on both axes.
Sample data here https://pastebin.com/MaEkwBwf

I'm  trying to get a fit for that but I don't have a good grasp on how to pass the aray to NonLinearModelFit
The function I'm trying to fit is
a = 150000;
x0 = 100;
y0 = 100;
sx = 5;
sy = 10;
th = Pi/4;
Plot3D[
 a*Exp[-(
     (Cos[th]*x - Sin[th]*y - (Cos[th]*x0 - Sin[th]*y0))^2/(2*
         sx^2) + (Sin[th]*x + 
          Cos[th]*y - (Sin[th]*x0 + Cos[th]*y0))^2/(2*sy^2)
     )]
 , {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]

In this case the free parameters would be a, x0, y0, sx, sy, th

NonlinearModelFit[
 data,
 a*Exp[-(
     (Cos[th]*x - Sin[th]*y - (Cos[th]*x0 - Sin[th]*y0))^2/(2*
         sx^2) + (Sin[th]*x + 
          Cos[th]*y - (Sin[th]*x0 + Cos[th]*y0))^2/(2*sy^2)
     )],
 {a, x0, y0, sx, sy, th},
 {x, y}]

NonlinearModelFit::Number of coordinates (200) is not equal to the number of variables (2).


Your dataset is consistent with the values being counts (i.e., non-negative integers).  Is that from some random sample?  Or are those measurements that were rounded to integers?  If the former, you should not be using NonlinearModelFit and you should sue whoever taught you to consider that.

Yes these are events of ion impacts on a detector and recorded by a CMOS camera. However the impacts are larger than 1 pixel. I'm trying to find the center of the distribution, and the properties of the distribution.

I'm not understanding where the sines and cosines come from as that's not a standard way to define a bivariate normal function.  However, if you're willing/able to assume a bivariate normal function for the counts, then just finding the horizontal and vertical means will get you the location of the peak.  No need to determine the orientation of the bivariate surface (if that's what the sines and cosines are for).

For experimental reasons the particules measured propagate at 45° of the camera sensor array. I want to measure the angle and the distribution across the propagation axis (the long axis) and across it (short axis). Any significant deviation from 45° mean there is an issue.

@JimB Why is NonlinearModelFit not appropriate for camera counts? Or do you mean if they are from a random sample it's incorrect? Can you elucidate?

@Tapiocaweasel  Let me count the ways.  First, it is how the data is collected and how that is incorporated into the model structure that one needs to consider.  The values of the data alone do not contain that necessary information to produce a reliable estimate along with some appropriate measure of precision.  If what one has is a random sample from a bivariate distribution where the sample values have been binned, then that has been binned, then techniques like maximum likelihood, method of moments, etc. should be used.  (To be continued....)

@Tapiocaweasel If one is considering a regression, then the regression error structure needs to be explicitly considered to provide estimators with known characteristics.  For estimating a surface that has the shape of a bivariate normal density, consider that estimates of the surface function won't be negative and that the errors (differences in the observed and predicted values) won't be equal for all points on the surface.  And equal variability is the default assumption in NonlinearModelFit.  One can certainly put in weights but those weights need to be known.  (Just a little more...)

@Tapiocaweasel The actual sample size also needs to be considered.  It appears that the individual samples are really clusters of "impacts" rather than a frequency of counts at a grid point.  So there are 2 levels of errors:  Impacts and the variability within an impact.  NonlinearModelFit (and LinearModelFit) can only handle one level of error.  Hence, NonlinearModelFit can't handle the way the data arises in this case.  The OP's question is very interesting.  (Finally, the end.)

This is an extended "question" about the generation of the data and a comment about the regression approach.
You mention in a comment that "the impacts are larger than 1 pixel."  If one plots just the values where the count is greater than zero, one sees the following:
wData = Flatten[Table[{i - 1, j - 1, data[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 201}, {j, 1, 201}], 1];
wData = Select[wData, #[[3]] > 0 &];
ListPlot[wData[[All, {1, 2}]], AspectRatio -> 1]


Are the "blobs" of an approximately 10-pixel diameter isolated impacts?  With the larger blob in the center representing multiple and overlapping impacts?  Do you only have the resulting total counts or do you have the counts for each impact?
I ask these questions because (1) The pattern does not seem to be bivariate Gaussian, (2) the outlying "impacts" can have a strong influence on the estimates and (3) your approach does not provide (so far) estimates of precision for the central location nor for the angle.

And if the impacts are all of similar size, then it appears that there are around 500 impacts.

"Are the "blobs" of an approximately 10-pixel diameter isolated impacts?" > Yes
"With the larger blob in the center representing multiple and overlapping impacts?" > also yes. I cannot generally get individual counts for the center as there are too many events accumulating there.

Here's an approach using an estimate of the covariance matrix.
(* Get positive counts and grid location *)
wData = Flatten[Table[{i - 1, j - 1, data[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 201}, {j, 1, 201}], 1];
wData = Select[wData, #[[3]] > 0 &];  (* Only keep counts greater than zero to speed things up *)

(* Calculate means, variances, and covariance *)
m1 = wData[[All, 1]] . wData[[All, 3]]/Total[wData[[All, 3]]];
m2 = wData[[All, 2]] . wData[[All, 3]]/Total[wData[[All, 3]]];
v1 = Sum[(wData[[i, 1]] - m1)^2  wData[[i, 3]], {i, 1, Length[wData]}]/Total[wData[[All, 3]]];
v2 = Sum[(wData[[i, 2]] - m2)^2  wData[[i, 3]], {i, 1, Length[wData]}]/Total[wData[[All, 3]]];
cov = Sum[(wData[[i, 1]] - m1) (wData[[i, 2]] - m2) wData[[i, 3]],
 {i, 1, Length[wData]}]/Total[wData[[All, 3]]];

(* Construct estimate of covariance matrix *)
covMatrix = {{v1, cov}, {cov, v2}};
(* Compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors *)
{eigenvalues, eigenvectors} = Eigensystem[covMatrix];
(* Identify the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue *)
maxEigenvalueIndex = Ordering[eigenvalues, -1][[1]];
eigenvector = eigenvectors[[maxEigenvalueIndex]];
(* Calculate the angle in degrees *)
angle = (180/Pi) ArcTan[eigenvector[[1]], eigenvector[[2]]]
(* 39.8213 *)

The estimate of the peak location is just {m1, m2}.  Unfortunately, the only way I know of to calculate a measure of precision for the estimated angle is using a bootstrap approach. But that would require knowing the individual impacts to be appropriate.  An appropriate bootstrap measure of precision for the peak location would also require knowing the individual impacts.

FWIW, you can just create an empirical distribution dist = EmpiricalDistribution[wData[[All, 3]] -> wData[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]; and then calculate the mean and covariance μ = Mean@dist;
Σ = Covariance@dist;

Actually I take this back, the means agree but the covariance of my suggestion differs.

@ydd  You're first comment was correct.  I had the wrong index value for estimating the the second variance.  That is now fixed land the estimates for the covariance match (although it didn't change the estimate of the angle by very much).

I have managed to figure it out, posting in case that helps someone later. I had to flatten the data in the form of response = f(x,y)
dataflat = Flatten[Table[{i, j, data[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 200}, {j, 1, 200}], 1];
model = NonlinearModelFit[
  dataflat,
  a*Exp[-(
      (Cos[th]*x - Sin[th]*y - (Cos[th]*x0 - Sin[th]*y0))^2/(2*
          sx^2) + (Sin[th]*x + 
           Cos[th]*y - (Sin[th]*x0 + Cos[th]*y0))^2/(2*sy^2)
      )],
  {{a, 150000}, {x0, 100}, {y0, 100}, {sx, 3}, {sy, 3}, th}, {x, y}]

Produces a fit
Show[{
  Plot3D[model[x, y], {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListPlot3D[data, PlotStyle -> None, MeshStyle -> Red]
  }]


The colors are terrible, but it fits correctly and identifies the 45° correctly (in that example the fit outputs 46.4°)

You data has dimensions of 201 x 201 which suggests you want to use {i, 1, 201} rather than {i, 1, 200} in your code.  While that doesn't change the estimate of the angle using  your approach, it does drop off one row and one column.
